# Using GHC API to compile a program with optimisation

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-api

I want to compile a Haskell module to GHC Core, with optimisations applied, and use the resulting core output. However, when I use `compileToCoreSimplified` it doesn't seem to run all the normal optimisations. Taking the program:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}
module LensOpt(pick) where
import Control.Lens
data Record = Record {_field :: String}
field = lens _field $ \r x -> r{_field=x}
pick = Record "test" ^. field
```

When run through `ghc -ddump-simple` I get the optimal output:

```
LensOpt.pick1 :: GHC.Prim.Addr#
LensOpt.pick1 = "test"#

pick :: String
pick = GHC.CString.unpackCString# LensOpt.pick1
```

However, when compiled using `compileToCoreSimplified` I get the output:

```
s1 :: Addr#
s1 = "test"#

s2 :: [Char]
s2 = unpackCString# s1

s3 :: Record
s3 = Record s2

pick :: String
pick = case s3 of { Record ds -> ds }
```

I am invoking `compileToCoreSimplified` with:

```
import GHC
import GhcPlugins
import GHC.Paths

main = runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
    setTargets []
    dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
    setSessionDynFlags dflags{hscTarget = HscNothing}
    res <- compileToCoreSimplified "LensOpt.hs"
    liftIO $ writeFile "lens_api.txt" $ showSDoc dflags $ ppr res
```

How do I drive the GHC API to apply the full optimisations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn on the optimizations you want to run in the `DynFlags`.

You can do that either by specifying an optimization level (0..2) and setting optimizations based on that ([`updOptLevel`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-lib-0.20190204/docs/DynFlags.html#v:updOptLevel)), or by turning on individual optimizations such as [`Opt_Specialise`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-lib-0.20190204/docs/DynFlags.html#t:GeneralFlag):

```
main = runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
    setTargets []
    dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
    setSessionDynFlags $ updOptLevel 2 $ dflags{hscTarget = HscNothing}
```